# How can I generate custom image format thumbnails?

Tags: nautilus, customization, thumbnails

I'm trying to get thumbnails to appear for a custom image format in Nautilus on 19.04. The problem I'm running into is the thumbnails will only be generated once I open the files (.VTF "`image/x-vtf`" Valve Texture Format in my case) in GIMP which defeats the need/purpose of thumbnails in the first place.

I feel like I must be missing something. I added the MIME type and updated the thumbnailer with the proper .so file (`libpixbufloader-vtf.so`) but still cannot seem to figure out why thumbnails aren't being generated before loading the file in an editor.

Does anyone know why this might be or some steps I can try to resolve this?